# $16$ men can finish $80$% work in $24$ days..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$16$ men can finish $80$% work in $24$ days. When should $8$ men leave the work so that the whole work is completed in $40$ days? (Answer: $20$days).

MY Attempt:

in $24$ days, $16$ men can do $\dfrac {4}{5}$ work.
In $1$ day, $16$ men can do $\dfrac {1}{30}$ work.
In $1$ day, $1$ man can do $\dfrac {1}{480}$ work.

now, what is the simplest method to complete it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t$ be the number of days when the 8 men leave. Then, the amount of work  $w(u)$ finished after working for $u$ days is given by

$$w(u)=\frac{(16-8)\cdot u}{480}+\frac{8t}{480}$$

(assuming that $u>t$). The first term corresponds to 16-8 men working all u days. The second term is the additional 8 men that work only the first $t$ days. Now, solve for $t$ in $w(40)=1$.

Edit: How to get $w(u)$: As another example, assume $p$ men work for $u$ days. As you have already pointed out, one man does $\frac{1}{480}$ of the entire work. So, if $p$ men work for $u$ days, you get done $\frac{pu}{480}$ of the work. You can write $w(u)=\frac{pu}{480}$ to make the number of days worked $u$ a variable.

Now for my expression of $w(u)$: I've split the amount of work done into two parts, depending on the number of men working. You can assume that 16-8 men work for the entire time, i.e. $u$ days. This is the first term. In addition, in the first $t$ days 8 extra men work (which will be removed from the team after $t$ days). This corresponds to the second term.

Comment: how is $w(u)=....$?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler What exactly is not clear?

Comment: I did understand the function $w(u)$!

Comment: @LeonhardEuler I added some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

OK, with 1 man doing $\frac{1}{480}$ of the work, 480 'man-days' of work are needed. The 16 men perform 16 man-days of work per day for $x$ days, after which the 8 men get 8 'man-days' of work done for another $40-x$ days.

So: $16x + 8(40-x) =480$

Thus: $8x +320=480$

Hence: $8x=160$

Therefore: $x=20$

Comment: I didn't understand this : "of the work, 480 'man-days' of work are needed. The 16 men perform 16 man-days of work per day for x 
x
 days, after which the 8 men get 8 'man-days' of work done for another 40−x 
40−x
 days."?

Comment: OK, think about it this way. Suppose the whole job is to empty out 480 big containers, and that 1 man empties out 1 container per day (because you figured out 1 man does 1/480 of the work). Notice that with 16 men working, it would indeed take 30 days to finish the job. But now we have 16 men work for some number ($x$) of days, and after that it is just 8, for another $40 -x$ days (since we are told the finish the job in 40 days). So for the first $x$ days they finish $16x$ containers, and after that they finish $8(40-x)$ containers, for a total of 480 containers. So: $16x + 8(40-x) =480$.

Answer (score 0):

As 16  men can finish 80% work in 24 days so 80 % work = 16*24 units 
so total work = 100/80 *24*16 = 480 units
work need to be completed in 40 days. 
so let after n days 8 men left the job then 
16*n + 8*(40-n) = 480
8n + 320 = 480
n = 20
so after 20 days 8 men left the job.